# Natural unit conversions within HEP

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model, unit-conversion

In HEP, with the $$\hbar = c = 1 \;.$$ We have $$\hbar c =   200 \;\mathrm{MeV \cdot fm}$$

1 second is equivalent to $10^{-25}$ GeV. How these relations are used to convert seconds to GeV, GeV to seconds.

Comment: Punctuation related to block-set equations is generally typeset on the same line as the equation, and it is typical to use either a thin-space (`\,`) or a central dot (`\cdot`) to separate unit symbols.

Comment: You have studied [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#%22Natural_units%22_(particle_physics_and_cosmology)) and found it lacking?

Comment: see http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~avery/course/4390/f2015/lectures/natural_units.pdf

Answer (score 4):

In natural units, seconds and gigaelectronvolts (i.e., time and energy) are *inversely* related. You cannot convert GeV to seconds, but you can convert GeV$^{-1}$ to seconds.

The value of the reduced Planck constant is

$$\hbar=1.055\times 10^{-34}\text{ J}\cdot\text{s}=6.582\times 10^{-25}\text{ GeV}\cdot\text{s}.$$

If you use units where it is $1$, then you are taking

$$1\text{ GeV}^{-1}=6.582\times 10^{-25}\text{ s}.$$

Comment: formulas missing

Comment: in my browser There is nothing after  t"reduced Plamnck constant" nor after "you are taking". I am using Chrome.

Comment: @annav They show just fine for me. Can you see formulas in other posts, or is it just this one?

Comment: This is the first time  I have observed this. I will try Firefox.

Comment: On Firfox it is OK !!!!!

Comment: next time this happens I will go into "edit" . It is there also on edit.   I wonder if it is th $$ that chrome does not recognize as $1$  comes up fine.

Comment: Just tried it in an answer, it sees $1$  but    the 1  with  two $  gets a lot of spacing

Comment: @annav You might try reporting it as a bug on the mother meta as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111070/380389), or contact the SE team. Us mods don't have any special access to the site software so I'm not sure how we could help.

Comment: @Chris if you read my further comments i think it looks like a Chrome bug. , it is OK with explore rand firefox. I will just keep it in mind if I see again such discrpancies before flagging :)